# Count and Order By Foreign Key but use another column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I got following two tables.

```
class tbl_vocabulary(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    word = db.Column(db.String(32), index=True)
    gram_term_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tbl_grammatical_term.id'))

class tbl_grammatical_term(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    short_name = db.Column(db.String(16))
```

This is a simple 1:N relation, a grammatical term can belong to many vocabulary entries. I wanna get a list of how many nouns, verbs, etc are in the vocabulary.

I can get this with following query.

```
tbl_vocabulary.query.with_entities(tbl_grammatical_term.short_name, tbl_vocabulary.gram_term_id, func.count(tbl_grammatical_term.short_name)).outerjoin(tbl_grammatical_term).group_by(tbl_grammatical_term.short_name).all()
```

So I get a nested list like this:

```
[('ADV', 1, 15), ('N', 13, 137), ('V', 9, 48)]
```

Which has following information:

```
[(tbl_grammatical_term.short_name, tbl_vocabulary.gram_term_id, count)]
```

So how can I get rid of the tbl_vocabulary.gram_term_id?

Comment: if the list is small, then iterate again in list comprehension and just get the required fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a quick and dirty solution for extracting only the short_name and count from the result you can use list comprehension:

```py
a = [('ADV', 1, 15), ('N', 13, 137), ('V', 9, 48)]
b = [(x,z) for (x,_,z) in a]
```

`b` will then hold the following value:

```py
[('ADV', 15), ('N', 137), ('V', 48)]
```

Comment: `_` is generally accepted as a placeholder for data that you are required to unpack but don't need. So `b = [(x,y) for (x,_,y) in a]` might be clearer for a future maintainer.

Comment: I edited my original response based on the comment posted by @ac24.